# mule passing same payload to different processors

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I am having an xml in MULE which i am splitting in two parts using splitter,the problem i am facing is how to pass the same xml to each splitter? 
Can anyone help?

```
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
 <splitter1/>
 <splitter2/>
```

and there is processing and an outbound endpoint after each splitter.
Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Use `<all>` to do that

```
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
<all> 
 <splitter1/>
 <splitter2/>
</all>
```

`<all>` sends the same message to every message processor you include inside it.

Comment: yes but there is processing and endpoints after each splitter will it apply to both splitters then?

Comment: Can you give me more details of your config in your question. I don't get why would you need two splitters

Comment: My config is about splitting the xml data in two halves,the problem is while applying xpath logic for splitting the data i need two splitters one for the first half and second for the other like this : `xml data from inbound endpoint ,then <splitter1 evaluator="xpath" expression="first half"/> then dom-xml transformer <outbound endpoint> <splitter2 evaluator="xpath" expression="secondhalf"/> then dom-xml transformer <outbound endpoint>` this way i have to use two splitters